# UITextView horizontal scrolling

Tags: uitableview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I have a UITextView which wrapping words of long text and it have a vertical scrolling functionality. 
How can I switch off the word wrap, and switch on the horizontal scrolling with keep the vertical scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

i have seen this answer in stackoverflow only..

Let's say I want a scrollable width of 600 and a visible width of 250.

The first step is to make the UITextView a wide as the area you want to be scrollable. So what you would have put into contentSize, in this case 600.

Then the right inset is set to the difference between the actual width and the width you wanted. In this case 350.

This way cursor is restrained to the width you need BUT there is text visible to the right of your desired width, after all, the UITextView IS 600 pixels wide.

Now here's where the really hackish bit comes in, don't read on if you're sensitive or have a weak stomach.

Get an image of the user interface to the right where UITextView should end. Insert it into the NIB as an UIImage view and put it back in it's place, making sure that it's on top of the UITextView.

When the view is displayed, the cutout sits on top of the UITextView and hides the text overrun.